# Importing data from CSV in an existing Postgress table

Tags: database, postgresql, subquery

How to import data from a CSV file to an already existing table in PostgreSQL.I need to make just an addition to an existing table, but since the data is quite large i have imported it to csv.
Any suggestion will really be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`COPY`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html) SQL command or the `psql` command [`\copy`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-META-COMMANDS-COPY).

If you have requirements that exceed the capabilities of `COPY`, you might consider [`pgloader`](http://pgloader.io/).